# Solving for cross-covariances between two random vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables, statistical-inference, covariance

Let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be Gaussian random vectors with zero mean and covariances $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{xx}}$, $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{yy}}$, respectively. Define the sum of these processes as
$\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}$, with covariance
\begin{align}
    \mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{zz}}=\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{xx}}+\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{yy}}+\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{xy}}+\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{xy}}^\top.
\end{align}

Assume that I know $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{xx}}$ and that I have observations of $\mathbf{z}$. Is there a procedure for inferring $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{yy}}$ and $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{xy}}$?